# How to send su password automatically?

Tags: bash, ssh, password

How can I send the password automatically within the script below when I try to switch to `su`?

Currently I'm able to login via ssh to hostname entering automatically the `ssh password` using `sshpass` but in the process requests me the `su password`

```
# sshpass -p 'ssh_password' ssh myuser@$hostname "su -c \"cd /some/path/ && ls -l\""
You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
Password:
```

I've tried something like this,but is not working.

```
sshpass -p 'ssh_password' ssh myuser@$hostname "su myuser su_password -c \"cd /documents/backups/ && ls\""
```

Below I show 3 ways I've tested and only 3rd accepts the `su_password`, the other 2 requests password and when I enter it, answers with `su: incorrect password`

**1-) Trying with username and su_password (FAILS)**

```
# sshpass -p $ssh_password ssh -t $myuser@$hostname "su $myuser 'MysuPassword123' -c \"cd /some/path/ && ls\""
You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
Password:
su: incorrect password
Connection to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD closed.
```

**2-) Trying only with username  (FAILS)**

```
# sshpass -p $ssh_password ssh -t $myuser@$hostname "su $myuser -c \"cd /some/path/ && ls\""
You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
Password:
su: incorrect password
Connection to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD closed.
```

**3-) Trying only with `su` without username/su_password (Success)**

```
# sshpass -p $ssh_password ssh -t $myuser@$hostname "su -c \"cd /some/path/ && ls\""
You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
Password:
docs file1 file2
Connection to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD closed.
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "_is not working_". We're not with you so you have to explain it for us. What happened? What didn't happen? What did you expect to happen? What (error) messages did you get? What have you done to try and resolve the issue yourself?

Comment: Updated the attempts I made.

Comment: Do you have `sudo` on the remote system or do you _need_ to use `su`?

Comment: Only allowed to send su, not sudo

Comment: When `su` says `incorrect password`, is that after you have entered the password manually, or does it report that immediately before you have a chance to try entering it?

Comment: Appears `su: incorrect password` after I enter the password mannually

Comment: sounds like a job for [tag:expect]... Or maybe for a strategically placed SSH key in `~/.ssh` of the remote host's root.

Comment: @terdon, wouldn't sudo also ask for a password with the usual configuration?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, but you could do useful things with the sudoers file or pass the password to it (I forget how, on mobile now, but I know it's possible).

Comment: @terdon, yep. `sudo --stdin`, apparently, or tricks with `SUDO_ASKPASS`..

Comment: @ilkkachu ssh key is the right answer, IMO.

Comment: @JimL. ssh key will only help getting into the remote system as `user`, but the OP also needs to become root on the remote.

Comment: @terdon a restricted ssh key in ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys will permit root access to a specific command